# Python FTP download not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

I am trying to download a file from FTP using python. I was able to successfully move into the directory but can't download the file.

The command I use is `ftp.retrbinary('master.idx', open(fname,'wb').write)`

And error is below. It looks like the command is looking for `MASTER.IDX` instead of `master.idx`

The full path to the file I want to download is ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/full-index/2011/QTR2/master.idx

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 406, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 368, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 331, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 500 MASTER.IDX not understood
```

Comment: My guess is the fact that the filename comes back in MASTER.IDX is some sort of idiosyncrasy of that FTP server.

Comment: If you posted the whole program you have, it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say why the name changes to uppercase. In any case, when using FTP, I make like this, it may help you:

```
server = "URL.of.server"
directory = "directory/where/the/file/is"
filename = "nameoffile.txt"

from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(server) #Set server address
ftp.login()  # Connect to server
ftp.cwd(directory) # Move to the desired folder in server
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename,open(filename, 'wb').write) # Download file from server
ftp.close() # Close connection
```

I think that it may be the *'RETR '*, if you don't write, it the server may not understand what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

use `wget` module of python instead. Here is an example snippet

```
import wget
fileloc = '/path/to/the/file/foo.txt'
wget.download(fileloc)
```